# Flutter Pin Input Field

Tags: dart, flutter, material-design, material-ui, flutter-layout

I am trying to create [this pin input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R83KM.png) using flutter. I found a few examples like [this one](https://medium.com/developing-custom-flutter-pin-entry-textfield/developing-custom-flutter-pin-entry-textfield-7da8acb0a3fa) online but run into problems when it comes to scaling the input to fill the width of the container or performing validation - the user should only be allowed to enter numbers.

Is there a better way to go about this than the examples provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to reinvent the wheel, you can use a mature PIN plugin like [pin_code_text_field](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pin_code_text_field) and [pin_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pin_view). Some of them even provide great functionalities like `SMS Listening` if you intend to use them in the future in Verification. You also find a wide array of ready-made widgets that will make your development life much easier in the official [Dart packages](https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=) website.

Comment: Which of those two was the one with SMS Listening feature?

Comment: @Klesun it is `pin_view`, but as they mention on their package page they only support that feature on Android. However iOS detect verification messages by using heurestics, such as containing words like code and etc. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One more pin code package, I used it for creating locally stored pin code in the wallet app https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pin_code_widget

[image]